# My almost-correct SQL query gives an error

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM references WHERE title LIKE '%NSObject%'
```

Giving this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `references WHERE title LIKE '%NSObject%'` at line 1

However, I cannot find my mistake. What is wrong with this query?

Comment: Rename the `references` table to `references_table` or `my_refereneces` or `references_to_important_things`. As others have mentioned you can enclose it in backticks, but IMHO, it's better to avoid using keywords as names for your own objects whenever possible, so I usually apply some qualifier to make it clearer.

Comment: The problem is that it's not my database, and I don't have permissions to change its structure. The database is also already in use by some other apps.

Comment: @Time Machine: Ah yes, I know that sort of pain all too well. ;)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner why are you putting answers in comments?

Comment: @Keng: Quassnoi had pretty much answered the question already, I was just throwing in my 2¢ as a comment. I thought it was more of an opinion than an answer. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`references` is a reserved word.

Enclose it into backticks:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `references`
WHERE   title LIKE '%NSObject%'
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Please wait 7 minutes because of the stupid accept-delay. >.>

Comment: Better still, I'd come up with a different name for the table. Having table names that are reserved words is a recurring pain. A gift that keeps on giving.

Comment: I agree, it seems like alot of time reserved words are the ones you need the most. :)

Answer (score 3):

`References` is a key word

if you wrap references with backticks it will know that you are using `references` as a table or field name

like this

```
Select * from `references`
```